# Ableton: Why is my vectorscope showing flashes of stereo activity on a mono track?

Tags: ableton, phase

I've placed a utility on my master track and set the width to zero. Schwa's Schope plugin (set to phase visualisation) shows the expected hairline profile, but occasionally flips out for a split second or so and fills the scope with noise. Is this a phase issue?

Comment: Does it do it at the same point each time? What does it do when you're not summed to mono?

Comment: Aye, at the same point each time. It flickers like this in stereo too.

Comment: I'd suspect phase-glitch then. Try to isolate which track it's coming from, then zoom edit & see if you can actually see what's happening in the waveform. If you're tricksy, you can either draw it out or cross-fade a tiny bit of unaffected track into it. [caveat, I've never used Ableton, so idk *how* these things would be done in there.]

Comment: This sounds like top-notch advice. Thank you!